# When we run javafx application on virtual machine

Tags: javafx, virtual-machine

when we run our javafx application on Virtual machine with JDK 1.7
getting following errors :-

```
Stack: [0x3aba0000,0x3abf0000],  sp=0x3abeeab0,  free space=314k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [glass.dll+0x1016d]

[error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xc0000005]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinWindow._close(J)Z+0
j  com.sun.glass.ui.Window.close()V+51
j  com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.close()V+15
j  javafx.stage.Window$9.invalidated()V+567
j  javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid()V+13
j  javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(Z)V+31
j  javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Z)V+11
j  javafx.stage.Window.hide()V+2
j  com.org.modules.dlmgr.ui.DownloadManagerUI.hideWindow()Z+11
j  com.org.modules.dlmgr.ui.DownloadManagerUI.startSysTray()Z+233
j  com.org.modules.dlmgr.ui.DownloadManagerUI.start(Ljavafx/stage/Stage;)V+273
j  com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run()V+26
j  com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run()V+4
j  com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+7
j  com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run()V+12
j  com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run()V+4
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop([Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/sun/glass/ui/Launchable;)V+0
j  com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Lcom/sun/glass/ui/win/WinApplication;[Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/sun/glass/ui/Launchable;)V+3
j  com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run()V+32
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Can anybody tell me how to resolve this issue.
I have tried to pass -Xmx1300M but still getting above error.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You probably miss some packages. Try installing JRE 1.8 with at least the jfrxt.jar (you'll need that one for JavaFX). If that isn't working try installing a editor which already has the libraries.

F.E. (this is what I currently use)

Eclipse 4.4.0 with e(fx)clipse 1.2.0 as found:
[Here](http://efxclipse.bestsolution.at/install.html)